# Botón con fondo degradado en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, botón, background

si pueden ayudarme se los agradecería mucho, quería poner un botón en mi aplicación de Android Studio con fondo degradado, busque en internet y lo hacen de manera muy sencilla, solo crean un drawable y en el layout solo configuran el background, el problema es que a mi no me funciona, y la verdad no se me ocurre que podría estar mal.

este es el código del degradado (degradado.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#a06017" />
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#a06017" android:endColor="#260f00" />
</shape>
```

y este es el codigo de mi layout

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="MÁS INFORMACIÓN"
        android:background="@drawable/degradado"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Sin embargo no me hace el cambio del backgroung, se queda así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Ya logré solucionarlo, en themes.xml cambie el parent del style por "Theme.AppCompat"

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.TwoElements" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```